# python-social-auth throwing a TypeError when I call disconnect

Tags: django, mongoengine, django-socialauth

So, I'm using the python-social-auth app to allow users to login using Facebook of Google (OAuth2) on my site and I have the login and authentication parts working. The issue is when I try calling disconnect.

http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html#account-disconnection

All it specifies is to call it using a POST request and with CSRF protection which I do but I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError at /disconnect/facebook/
get_social_auth_for_user() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"    get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in     _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  32.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  41.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py" in disconnect
  35.                          redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/actions.py" in do_disconnect
  99.     strategy.disconnect(user=user, association_id=association_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/strategies/base.py" in disconnect
  83.                                                             association_id)
```

Following the stack trace doesn't help. This happens when I try disconnecting Google as well

Comment: There was a bug on mongoengine support which is fixed at https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/commit/7d1df148233d902363a3b64e32c5fad6b31dcf26, I'm assuming that you are using mongoengine storage since it's the only one not accepting 4 arguments.

Comment: I am getting the exactly same error, and I am using mysql. How to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

As omab said it was simply a bug in mongoengine support. The problem is fixed now if you check out from the master branch of the python-social-auth git repo